# How to parse HTML which required JavaScript with Objective-C

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

For some reason, I need to parse HTML of a website.

But the website 's content was blocked by the JavaScript.

And when I NSLog the string, the content of the HTML was not what I want.

**The wrong HTML**

```
</script><noscript><div class="error-container"><div class="wrapper"><header><a href="/"><img src="/resource/img/logo.png"><div class="title">Adobe Color CC</div></a></header><section><ul id="no-js" class="wrap"><li><h1>JavaScript Disabled</h1><p>Adobe Color CC requires JavaScript in order to load properly. **Please enable JavaScript in your browser and reload the page.**</p></li><li><h1>JavaScript est désactivé</h1><p>Pour pouvoir se charger correctement, Adobe Color CC requiert JavaScript. Veuillez activer JavaScript dans votre navigateur et recharger la page.</p></li><li><h1>JavaScript deaktiviert</h1><p>JavaScript ist erforderlich, damit Adobe Color CC ordnungsgemäß geladen wird. Aktivieren Sie JavaScript im Browser und laden Sie die Seite neu.</p></li><li><h1>JavaScript が無効です</h1><p>Adobe Color CC で正しく読み込みを行うには、JavaScript が必要です。ご使用のブラウザーで JavaScript を有効にして、ページを再読み込みしてください。`
```

**Get content Method**

```
NSURL *htmlUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://color.adobe.com/explore/newest/?time=all"];

NSStringEncoding htmlEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:htmlUrl encoding:htmlEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",htmlString);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithContentsOfURL` is really not designed for this. It's meant to take in data, such as JSON or XML which is static.

I would suggest using other networking classes instead which will provide more control as well as the ability to make it asynchronous. The answers to [Making stringWithContentsOfURL asynchronous - Is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11621269/1091402) should provide some more detail.